# Div position absolute at top window

Tags: jquery, window, absolute, css-position

Is there any way in jquery to position a div that has position:absolute in css and his parent has position:relative, to the top of the window ?
The div i am refering its part of a carousel so his position will change always, but no matter of his parent position i want this div to always stay at the top of the browser window.
If there is a way to calculate this div how far from window top position it is and than jquery to change the top position based on that, thank you.
The div absolute its slide-right and the div relative its swiper-slide but they both change postion in this carousel and slide-right its hidden until clicked when it shows and i need it to always show from top of window.

```
  <div class="swiper-slide">
  <div class="slide-left">
  <div class="slider_arrow"></div> 
  <img src="images/iDangerous/img_thumb1_hover.png"   
  class=""  alt=".">
  </div><!-- end slide-left-->
   <div class="slide-right"> 
   <h1>Foundation Stone Laying Ceremony</h1>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum in Hong Kong celebrates the construction of a new primary and     secondary campus in Kowloon Bay with a Foundation Stone Laying Ceremony</p>
   </div><!-- end slide-right-->
  </div><!-- end swiper-slide-->
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `offset()` method to determine parent element placement relative to document. Then subtract the top and left values from zero to apply to child:

```
var parentOffset=$('#parent').offset();
$('#child').css({top: 0- parentOffset.top, left:0- parentOffset.left});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/mTqcP/

API reference: http://api.jquery.com/offset

Comment: Sound good, i will test tomorrow as i dont have acces to server at home ,and let you know if it worked, thank you.

Comment: the problem is that the "#number1" div in my css doesnt have the height added, its done dynamically so i need to find always the offset of the "#number1" relative to the window height so i can substract this from the top position of the "#number2" div.
let me know if this is clear, thank you

Comment: its ok i used another method unrelated to this thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to move the relative>parent div on dom ready and every window [`resize`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/). Also uses jquery `offset()` functions' width and height object params

http://jsbin.com/uziyes/1/edit